# How can I prevent using API_PREFIX in Lumen service?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I am using Lumen service for my project. I do not want to have api word in the route address. I know it comes from

```
 API_PREFIX=api
```

in .env file but I do not know how can I prevent using this ?

My route address is it now :

> http://localhost/my_service/public/api/auth/login

and I want to change it to :

> http://localhost/my_service/public/auth/login

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change API_PREFIX=api to API_PREFIX= and add your api domain like this:
API_DOMAIN=https://api.example.com

Comment: Thanks a lot. When I uploaded my project on the host, (I have a subdomain for API), I wanted to prevent two API word in the address. The point is that I do not have API_DOMAIN config in the .env file so I added manually and It is working fine.

Comment: do you have any idea how can I do it on the localhost ?

Comment: You need to setup a local dns server for that purpose. If you are on windows, you need to add a record in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts to represent your domain. I personally use something like this: 127.0.0.1 mysite.me and this tells windows that mysite.me is located on the local server. The rest depends on your webserver configuration. You need to create a virtual host for this domain and point it to where your files are.